# MySQL C API: check if a field exists

Tags: mysql, c, linux

I'm new to mysql programming on c. I need to check if a certain user exists in a table. How can I do this using the C API?
Here's what I've got, but it isn't working:

```
if (mysql_query(con, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='user3'")) 
  {
      finish_with_error(con);
  }      
  MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);
  if (result == NULL) 
  {
      finish_with_error(con);
  }
  int count = mysql_field_count(con);
  printf("%d\n", count );
```

Comment: In what way does it fail? Please include relevant error messages.

Comment: Check the `MYSQL_FIELD` type, and use `mysql_fetch_field`, then you can do something like `MYSQL_FIELD *field = mysql_fetch_field(result); printf("%s\n", field->name);` [API data structures are listed here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-data-structures.html)

Comment: I always get a count of '1', with current code.

Comment: Field refers to columns. You want to count rows. Try  calling `mysql_fetch_row` - if you get a row then the user exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, this is something I wrote using the comments, and finally ended up using.

```
if (mysql_query(con, "SELECT field FROM table WHERE userName='user1'")) 
{
    finish_with_error(con);
}

MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);

if (result == NULL) 
{
    finish_with_error(con);
}  

MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL_FIELD *field;

if (row = mysql_fetch_row(result))
{
    printf("%s\n", row[0]);
    db_pwd = row[0];
}
```